# Optional was found nil when downloading image using DispatchQueue swift 3

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiimage, option-type

I am using DispatchQueue.global() to download images from urls that are stored in an array url, these are the steps:

```
Array of urls --> let data = contentsOf: array[url] --> display img
```

however I get an error like, check the image below:

[image: Problem]

and this is what gets print out:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

code in text format:

```
func updateView(){

    for i in 0..<testArray1.count {

        let ImgUrl = URL (string: testArray1[i])!

        DispatchQueue.global().async {

            do {

                let data = try Data(contentsOf: ImgUrl)
                DispatchQueue.global().sync {

                    self.imgArr.append(UIImage(data: data)!)

                }

            } catch {
                //handle the error
            }
        }

    }
}
```

hope this can help you help me.

thank you in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that you got that data but not failed to create the image. Try this

```
        DispatchQueue.global().sync {
            for i in 0..<testArray1.count {
                let imgUrl = URL(string: testArray1[i])!

                do {
                    let data = try Data(contentsOf: imgUrl as URL)
                    if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                        imgArr.append(image)
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("Unable to load data: \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This works fine, however, i am grabbing 162 images from the array and the urls are online, is there anyway to display the images that has been added to the image array while the others are being downloaded? @Lawliet

Comment: Well, it sounds like another question, but anyway you can create a caches array to store the images and show what you loaded. Take a look at this example http://www.kaleidosblog.com/uicollectionview-image-gallery-download-and-display-images-inside-the-cell

Comment: Yh i know another questiion sorry

Comment: Check again http://www.kaleidosblog.com/uicollectionview-image-gallery-download-and-display-images-inside-the-cell It works for me.